# Why are the latent space outputs of my autoencoder not the shape I expected?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here is where I'm at. I built and trained an autoencoder in tensorflow. The model summary looks like so:

```
Model: "model_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, None, None, 3)]   0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 4)     112       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, None, None, 16)    592       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, None, None, 32)    544       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_6 (Dense)              (None, None, None, 8)     264       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, None, None, 32)    288       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_2 (Conv2DTr (None, None, None, 16)    4624      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_3 (Conv2DTr (None, None, None, 3)     435       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,859
Trainable params: 6,859
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The layer 'dense_6' is my latent space. Now, I am passing through a (256,256,3) image into the encoder part and am getting out (1, 252, 252, 8) tensor. Obviously, the output shape is listed as (None, None, None, 8), so it makes sense that I am getting this tensor out, but I was expecting to get just an 8-dimensional vector out.

Did I design my autoencoder wrong maybe? I'm quite confused and could definitely use some clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was doing wrong. Yes, I built the autoencoder wrong. I didn't think about how I need to flatten the tensor before passing it into a dense layer. Important step but easy to forget...

Here is my new model summary in case someone else needs some guidance:

```
Model: "model_18"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_16 (InputLayer)        [(None, 256, 256, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_30 (Conv2D)           (None, 254, 254, 4)       112       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_31 (Conv2D)           (None, 252, 252, 16)      592       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_11 (MaxPooling (None, 126, 126, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_12 (Flatten)         (None, 254016)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_32 (Dense)             (None, 16)                4064272   
_________________________________________________________________
latent (Dense)               (None, 8)                 136       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_33 (Dense)             (None, 16)                144       
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_11 (Reshape)         (None, 252, 252, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_26 (Conv2DT (None, 254, 254, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_transpose_27 (Conv2DT (None, 256, 256, 3)       435       
=================================================================
Total params: 4,066,139
Trainable params: 4,066,139
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```